# How to know if radio button with specific id is checked to use in if else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to do is to show the dialogbox if all the inputs are empty. And if the Yes radio button is checked the other inputs with asterisk should be filled also or else the dialog will show up.

My problem is even i checked the radio button with a value of Yes the dialog wont show up.

current output: http://jsfiddle.net/5kcsn/245/

script:

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: 140,
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
        "Close": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

$('#presentEmploymentInformationDialog').click(function () {
    if (   
    ($("input[name='employed']:checked").val() == undefined) && 
    (
    ($('#employed_v1[value=Yes]:checked').val() == 'true') ||
    ($("input[name='presentEmployed']:checked").val() == undefined || $('#officeName').val() == '' || $('#officeAddress').val() == '' || $('#jobPosition').val() == '' || $('#noYearsInPosition').val() == '' || $('#statusOfEmployment').val() == '' )
    )
       )
    {
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
    }else{
        exit;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use following code to see if a checkbox is selected

```
$("selector").is(":checked")
```

Here is example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aimeeborda/kuf4P/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#presentEmploymentInformationDialog').click(function() {
  if($('input[name="employed"]:checked').val() === 'Yes' && $('.row input[type="text"], .row select').val() === '') {
     $('#dialog-confirm').dialog("open");
  }
  else{
     $('.show-page[data-page="Eligibilty_info"]').trigger('click');
  }
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/5kcsn/250/)**

Comment: the dialog should only show if all the inputs are empty and if the radio button with yes value is clicked. In your code if i click no the dialog shows up.

Comment: and if i click yes in ur code some inputs with asterisk even its empty the dialog wont show up.

Comment: Sorry I copied your code but as you can see in the fiddle dialog shows on submit.

Comment: @user3842025 is very hard to understand the rules based on your existing code

Comment: @mdesdev u only just delete the circle brace in my code thats why =.=

Comment: I edited my answer, now only if `employed` [Yes] is checked and inputs are empty dialog shows.

Comment: @mdesdev if all the inputs include radio button are empty the dialog shows up. And if the user click Yes the user should fill all the inputs with an asterisk in their name or the dialog will shows up again if they press the button.

Comment: @mdesdev thats the idea that i want to do in my code.

Answer (score 0):

you are over complicating your selectors and causing at least one test that can never work.

Example:

```
$('#employed_v1[value=Yes]:checked').val() == 'true')
```

This can never evaluate true. In the selector you say the value is `Yes` but then try to compare it to `'true'`.
Id's must be unique so there can only be one `#employed_v1` so just use that as the selector.

You might want to use something like this for the  radios which cuts down some code

```
$('[name="employed"]:checked').length /* if 0 neither is checked */
```

For the text inputs you could use `filter()` on them

```
 var invalidTextFields= $('#officeName, #officeAddress,#jobPosition.....').filter(function(){
        return this.value=='';
 }).length;
```

The main difficulty in debugging what you have is there are too many `||` chained together with suspect selectors mixed in

Comment: can you apply it in my jsfiddle?

Comment: not totally... I really don't get what requirements are.